# understand sge task related variables in python

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code:

```
for idx,row in enumerate( islice(chain.from_iterable(
     repeat(load),task_id, min(task_id +step_size, last_step))):
```

So, where shall I get started with this code? I sincerely hope this is not a trivial question. Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: someone you know loves [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Unfortunately, a number of functions inside that piece of code have lost their namespace. NightShadeQueen already points you to the itertools documentation, but there should also be a part earlier in the code along the lines of `from itertools import islice, chain, repeat`. Otherwise, it's largely reading through the Python documentation (or do general searches for "python <function>").

Comment: well, I did not find things like 'from itertools import islice, chain, repeat' somewhere earlier in the program.

Comment: `from itertools import *`, maybe?

Comment: Yes. You are right !